# SharePoint 2013 - Custom WebPartPage for List Form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, custom-form, display-form

I'm looking to add related lists to a Display Form for a list and tie them together with filters.

I can create a new custom Display Form in SPD and add the related web parts with filters based of the item's DispForm ID.

However, I'm looking to create a page with a left (body) and right web part zone so I can place the item's main DispForm web part in the left column and all of the associated list web parts off to the right.

Creating a new custom list form web part only allows me to create a new page with a single web part zone.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
BL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the form page (ASPX-file) in the SharePoint Designer and add as many web part zones as you need.

Also, I'd recommend you truing [Plumsail Forms Designer](https://spform.com/) for creating a form with [related items](https://spform.com/documentation/related-items-regular-mode) without coding. The software itself is not free but saves a lot of time so finally it will cost less than if you'd implement the same by yourself.